# On press of submit button, a new view is created on separate storyboard - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating an app at the moment which involves inputting information into a 'Create Task' View Controller and upon pressing the Submit button, it moves the User back to the Homepage, and a new View is created in a TableView/ScrollView with the task data pulled through.

The structure would be:

- Create a task storyboard: User inputs a name, uploads a picture, selects a category, enters a description and picks a date
- They then press Submit, and are segued back to the home storyboard.
- The info from the task storyboard: name, picture, category, date are pulled into a view, contained within a tableview/stackview (not sure which is better)
- The view is, for example, 90% wide and 15px tall - with certain other properties

At the moment I'm just trying to create a View once the button is pressed, and then I'll work on pulling the data through separately afterwards, but I'm new to Swift and I can't work out how to do it.

Would I use a segue from the submit button back, and create a function that then creates a new entry in the table? Would anybody be able to provide a structure for the code that I'd use for this, or a URL to a site that could walk me through the process?

I can't find anything online - but figure that may be because I'm using the wrong terms to search.

If anybody could be kind enough to help, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `tableView.reloadData()` ? If you didn't use you can use. But if you used, you should be open more. Maybe you can share your code.

I hope this helped you.